# What is the solution for 'PageJacking'?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, information-retrieval

'PageJacking' is creating a website which looks good to 'WebCrawlers' and to normal users it i will show Advertisement / Promotional Content. Simply a website pretends Good Boy to 'Webcrawler', whereas to the users not .

Wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagejacking

How can a crawler avoid faking websites (PageJacking) ?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to avoid exactly? Are you designing a web crawler?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i am not building crawler right now. curious to know how the crawler avoid 'pagejacking' ?

Comment: It depends how or why pagejacking is a problem for the crawler.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz..yes. true. but no point in indexing, crawling and ranking a website which is faking.

Comment: But no harm in doing so either, since once it's reported you can just remove the listing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, ok :-).. as mentioned in the wiki, if the website is clever is enough to find a 'rare terms' and attach with fake content. it is a possibility that faking site can be ranked higher, even inbound links are less (because it is rare term, so no effect of page ranking)..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

[User agent spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing).

A search engine could send out two bots:

- a bot with the true `User-Agent` HTTP header (revealing itself as being a search engine bot)
- a bot with a typical browser’s `User-Agent` HTTP header (mimicking a human visitor)

Now the search engine could compare the results those two bots got.